# What is the genus of this fungus?

Tags: species-identification, microbiology, mycology

[image: Fungi Identification]

I'm struggling to identify this fungus. Is it *Aspergillus* sp. or *Penicillium* sp.?

Comment: Welcome to the Biology Stack Exchange. You would need to provide much clearer photos and some photographs down a microscope of the structures seen, particularly the sporangia for ID.